# Why limit function takes only int as argument?

Tags: python, pyspark, limit

I am using pyspark and want to take the first n rows of my dataframe. There is a function called `limit`. However it takes only `int` as parameter. Is there any way to call it with bigger values? This code will result in exception:

```
import sys

dataframe = spark.createDataFrame([('Alice',), ('Bob',)])
dataframe.limit(sys.maxsize)
```

Error:

```
An error occurred while calling o127.limit. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method limit([class java.lang.Long]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think it is valid requirement to extract `long` rows, is it not?

Comment: What is the question, why it happens or if there is any workaround??

Comment: The question is how to extract more rows that 32bit int (2,147,483,647).

Comment: Fortunately you set this clearly and unambiguously in the post...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in question `limit` function takes only `int` as input. But `sys.maxsize` return `long`, which is displayed in exception (`limit([class java.lang.Long])`). In order to run this without exception you need to `type cast` it to `int`.

Here is converted snippet:-

```
import sys

dataframe = spark.createDataFrame([('Alice',), ('Bob',)])
dataframe.limit(int(sys.maxsize))
```

Comment: This does not work. In python `int(sys.maxsize)` does nothing since `sys.maxsize` is alredy `int` albeit 64bit. Furthermore, I do want to extract possibly more rows than the limit of 32bit int, so something else than casting is needed, I think.

Comment: @MiroslavStola I checked this and found we can provide limit value within range of 32bit int. The alternative is you can add a new column and assign the row number to it. Then make a filter on this column so you can achieve limit.

Comment: Are there any plans to allow 64bit? The workaround seems reasonable. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @MiroslavStola sure, I will. What is your specific requirement, that you are looking for the limit function?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Requirement for the answer? Just move it from comment to separate answer. And add that if I want to be able to retrieve more then 32b, I have to create a new column of type `pyspark.sql.types.LongType`